# forcing four decimal places for double

Tags: c#

I need to display particular value to 4 decimal places for sure.

Here is the code

```
row["Money"] = StringMgt.ToGlobalizationString("N4", dblMoney);

public static string ToGlobalizationString(string format, double dblNumber)
{
    return dblNumber.ToString(format, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name));
}
```

Which outputs

```
1.4305228 to 1.4305 (which is fine!)

0.30704454 to 0.307 (I need to display 4 decimal places consistently)
```

How do I force it to display four decimal places (ex `0.3070`)? I have seen similar posts but did not understand properly.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [The `"#"` Custom Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#SpecifierD)

Comment: What does `ToGlobalizationString` do? `"N4"` is the proper standard format code to show 4 decimal places.

Comment: Is there a reason you create a new `CultureInfo` for each call?! If you replace `ToGlobalizationString()` with a simple `dblMoney.ToString("N4")` (to keep your code) it'll work exactly the same.

Comment: Where are you seeing `0.307`?  In a control?  In the debugger?

Comment: I tested `0.30704454.ToString("N4")` and it displayed what you want. Could the culture be affecting the results?

Comment: @D Stanley I always used F# for this. F.e.: F4 for 4 decimal places

Comment: @DStanley It is a method name. I will change format according to culture on the users machine. I am see that in the final result(displayed in a grid)

Comment: Why are you using `double` for money instead of `decimal`?

Comment: @CodesInChaos I changed variable name not realizing that money goes with decimal. I work for a company so security reasons before posting into forums like this, I always change the name of the methods and variables.

Comment: @user3490323 Is it possible that the grid is changing the string value _back_ to a number and then displaying that without any formatting?  Can you set the numeric formatting on the grid column?

Comment: @Serv "N" is similar to "F" except that it adds thousands separators (commas in the US)

Comment: Goddamnit. Because your Name starts with D I thought you wrote `D`. My bad. Sorry. But in this case. The F-specifier won't work either.

Answer (score 4):

So the way I understand it you need exactly four decimals, otherwise pad with 0 to the right. So it should be `.ToString("0.0000")`.

Comment: Looks like a bot or somebody with a lot of accounts

Comment: Well, maybe some folks think that anything __not__ pointing towards __Decimal__ for __money__ is __wrong advice__; I didn't downvote but I would agree.

Comment: @TaW I downvoted (some, like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24911148/1207195) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24911175/1207195)) answers here because they just made things even more complicate. The others...well honestly they're not _wrong_ because they works but they don't answer the question. In this case `number.ToString("N4")` must work exactly like `number.ToString("0.0000")` (or like `number.ToString("F4")` suggested by Serv). If first one doesn't work for OP then error is somewhere else. Well OP code has also other problems...

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the [F-Format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
void Main()
{
    double input = 3.213112134;
    string result = input.ToGlobalizationString("F4").Dump();
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static string ToGlobalizationString(this double input, string format)
    {
        return input.ToString(format, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name));
    }
}
```

This will return a string with 4 decimal points. Change it to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

Use following format:

```
row["Money"] = StringMgt.ToGlobalizationString("0.0000", dblMoney);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all the suggestions. If the output value has zero as the 4th decimal its not displaying it. for ex, instead of 0.3070 it is displaying 0.307. If thh fourth decimal is other than zero, it works just fine.

> example:
>
> ```
> Input value: 0.511519926 
> Output: 0.5115 
>
> Input Value: 0.45895644 
> Output Value: 0.459
> ```

I took off cultural settings and still it didn't work.

I did this and it worked

```
ClassA.gridTable.Columns[17].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "#,0.0000";
```

Thanks all for your valuable inputs.